# Read dynamically CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, for-loop

How I read CSV's files dynamically in Python, when change the suffix name files?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
uf = ['AC', 'AL', 'AP', 'AM', 'BA', 'CE', 'DF', 'ES', 'GO', 'MA', 'MT', 'MS', 'MG', 'PA', 'PB', 'PR', 'PE', 'PI', 'RJ', 'RN', 'RS', 'RO', 'RR', 'SC', 'SP1', 'SP2', 'SE', 'TO']
for n in uf:
   {n} = pd.read_csv('Basico_{n}.csv', encoding='latin1', sep=';', header=0)
```

The `{}` is not recognize into "for-loop".

I want to read the different file suffix names within in list items and create different DataFrames by same rules.

Comment: You can't do that. Nor would you want to. Add them to a dictionary instead of "variable variable names"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 2):

You have two main issues:

1. `{n} =` is invalid syntax. You can't assign to a variable name without messing with `locals` or `globals`. Doing so is almost always a *bad idea* anyway because it's much more difficult to programmatically access names that are, in a way, hard-coded. If the list of names is dynamic, then you need to start accessing `globals()` to get at them and this leads to bugs.
2. `'Basico_{n}.csv'` misses the `f` out of fstrings. `n` will not be added to the string if you don't specify that it's an f-string by prepending `f`.

Instead:

```
import pandas as pd
uf = ['AC', 'AL', 'AP', 'AM', 'BA', 'CE', 'DF', 'ES', 'GO', 'MA', 'MT', 'MS', 'MG', 'PA', 'PB', 'PR', 'PE', 'PI', 'RJ', 'RN', 'RS', 'RO', 'RR', 'SC', 'SP1', 'SP2', 'SE', 'TO']
dfs = {} # Create a dict to store the names
for n in uf:
   dfs[n] = pd.read_csv(f'Basico_{n}.csv', encoding='latin1', sep=';', header=0)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
'Basico_{n}.csv'
```

Will only work for python >= 3.6

Try

`{n} = pd.read_csv('Basico_{}.csv'.format(n), encoding='latin1', sep=';', header=0`)

Comment: It won't work at all because they forgot the leading `f`

Comment: Plus, the assignment is broken

Comment: Yes, because it doesn't work. It's invalid syntax. It makes a false assumption that python < 3.6 is the issue (that isn't the issue, they forgot the `f`) and even then it doesn't work with `.format`